# Is slice2 := slice1 equal to slice2 := slice1[:] in GoLang?

Tags: go, slice

Do the two following lines of code do the same thing in GoLang? What I want to do is to copy a slice into another one:

```
slice1 := make([]int, 5)
slice2 := slice1 #line1
slice2 := slice1[:] #line2
```

I run this code to test the behaviour, but apparently they both work int the same way:

```
func main() {
    s1 := make([]int, 5, 5)
    s1[2] = 33
    fmt.Printf("s1: %v: address of slice %p\n", s1, &s1)
    s2 := s1[:]
    s2[1] = 5
    fmt.Printf("s2: %v: address of slice %p\n", s2, &s2)
    s3 := s1
    s3[0] = 23
    fmt.Printf("s3: %v: address of slice %p\n",s3, &s3)
    fmt.Printf("s2: %v: address of slice %p\n", s2, &s2)
    fmt.Printf("s1: %v: address of slice %p\n", s1, &s1)
}
```

The output is:

```
s1: [0 0 33 0 0]: address of slice 0x40c0e0
s2: [0 5 33 0 0]: address of slice 0x40c100
s3: [23 5 33 0 0]: address of slice 0x40c120
s2: [23 5 33 0 0]: address of slice 0x40c100
s1: [23 5 33 0 0]: address of slice 0x40c0e0
```

So the memory addresses of the slices (s1, s2, s3) are different  but the pointers to the arrays contained into them, point to the same memory address.

I'm wondering if there is something that changes between this two ways, or if there is a sort of convention that says what's better to use.

Comment: The construct `slice[:]` isn’t ever used in real code, but I’ve seen a number of new users try to do this. Where are you finding documentation which led you to using it at all?

Comment: @JimB Basically it's only ever useful if applied on arrays.

Comment: @icza: yes, of course it's needed with arrays, and I figured it might be users cargo-culting the pattern with slices. I just was curious if there was some source that demonstrated this with slices in the first place, since it seems to come up more often than I'd expect.

Comment: @Stefano-Sambruna But you are using the right way to see the address. There is other way to safely copy the slice.

Comment: @icza you have just show how to check the size and cap of slices. But that does not ensure that whether the slices are same or not. Their address should be checked.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma Yes, that's correct, but copying and slicing a slice like that will always point to the same backing array as verified by the asker. My answer mainly focuses on the points missed by the asker.

Comment: @icza Yes, I know that. But in this case, there are ways to copy a slice into another one without pointing to the source slice.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma Yes, obviously, but this question isn't about that. As in the title, it asks if the 2 operations are the same.

Comment: But on the first line of question description the OP said, "What I want to do is to copy a slice into another one". That's why I'm concern about that and 've posted an answer.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma What do you mean?

Comment: I happened when I was talking with icza, then suddenly he stopped talking. instead of you were talking with me about the exactly same topic that i and icza were talking.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma man, seriously, is it all good at home?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is the same.

One thing you didn't check is the capacity, another property of slices. So let's check that one too:

```
s := make([]int, 2, 4)
s2 := s
s3 := s[:]

fmt.Println(len(s), cap(s))
fmt.Println(len(s2), cap(s2))
fmt.Println(len(s3), cap(s3))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uHMTEHyjssB)):

```
2 4
2 4
2 4
```

Basically the [slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) `s[:]` means to slice the slice, and use 0 as the lower index, and `len(s)` as the upper, and `cap(s)` as the capacity. So the result will be a slice identical to `s`.

For readability, just copy the slice header: `s2 := s`.

Also note that if `s` would be `nil`, both copying it and slicing it will also result in `nil` slices:

```
var s []int
s2 := s
s3 := s[:]

fmt.Println(len(s), cap(s), s == nil)
fmt.Println(len(s2), cap(s2), s2 == nil)
fmt.Println(len(s3), cap(s3), s3 == nil)
```

Output of the above is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lDjoDkFN4dN)):

```
0 0 true
0 0 true
0 0 true
```

So there is absolutely no difference in the result. A compiler implementation may or may not mimic the `s2 := s` statement when you write `s2 := s[:]`, so the latter *may* be slower. But again, there is no reason not to simply copy it.